# CASE WHEN SQL Query executes condition in else even if first condition is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to check if data exists in a table. First I check whether the table exists then I use a SELECT statement to check whether the table is empty or not

```
DECLARE @dataExists BIT = 0

SELECT 
             @dataExists = CASE 
                               WHEN OBJECT_ID('TableName') IS NULL 
                                  THEN 0 
                                  ELSE CASE 
                                          WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableName) 
                                             THEN 1 
                                             ELSE 0 
                                       END 
                            END

SELECT @dataExists
```

I have this query which is not supposed to execute `SELECT 1 FROM TableName` if `OBJECT_ID('TableName')` returns NULL but this query goes on and executes

```
SELECT 1 FROM TableName
```

which of course throws an error

> Invalid Object Name TableName

Comment: duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/does-sql-server-case-statement-evaluate-all-conditions-or-exit-on-first-true-con basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @dataExists BIT = 0

IF OBJECT_ID('TableName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @dataExists = (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableName)
END

SELECT @dataExists
```

The error you are getting is a compilation error. Since it's a single statement. SQL Server needs to build an execution plan, and can't do this, if the table doesn't exists.

By adding an `IF` the statement doesn't need to be "compiled" if the condition is not met.

With dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @TableName SysName = 'TableName'
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
DECLARE @dataExists BIT = 0

IF OBJECT_ID('''+@TableName+''') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @dataExists = (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+')
END

SELECT @dataExists
'

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Comment: is there any way to achieve above using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Sure, but why does non-dynamic SQL not suffice? Do you have a requirement to use dynamic SQL? If so, should've mentioned that from the outset.

Comment: how can i append '??